# Automating Webpage Interaction with Python

Tags: python, automation

Hello and thank you for reading this.

I work as a temp at a company and one of my main tasks is inventory clean up. I go through locations and delete materials less than one pound. The process to do so contains only a few steps. I have to log into the online system, navigate to the inventory page, search the page for material less than one pound and select them one at a time (which goes a new page) where I alter a text box and click 'enter' (sent to another page), I make to selections from two drop-down boxes then click 'save'.
What I want to do is automated this process, however the systems dept. won't provide me access to the database, which would make this task a thousand times easier, so it has to be client side. Is Selenium my best option here? Or what is the simplest way to do this?

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, selenium is absolutely your best option, and will get you up and running very quickly.

The official getting started guide should provide more than enough detail to accomplish this task, just don't `self.browser.close()` at the end of each unit test if you need the page to stay open. Don't bother with a heavy IDE, use *idle*.

And, note that you can only automate an older version of Firefox, or Chrome.

Guide:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Python is probably the easiest, yes. 
I would first have it generate a list of URLS for items less than one pound

And then I'm sure from there you have a specific set of buttons you press to filter by weight. I would do that and grab a list of products that you want to remove and can verify are the right ones. And then from there write a function that loads each url of each product and clicks the remove or delete button as you would.

Comment: Thank you, that was the same idea I had at first for a query request... pull all items that meet the requirement for user review then allow for user to act and remove all items. I didn't think about using the URL's though.